# How do you check the verison of compiler on VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I checked Tools and project properties and I still can't find it.

Anyone knows?

Default install of VS Professional 2010.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to right click a project ---> Properties -->  Target framework.

Each framework comes with a different compiler.